# reg.exe stays on process list after executing by WinExec()

Tags: c++, windows, io, registry, iostream

I have a problem similar to:
[Using Java runtime to add registry key, cause process reg.exe to run forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136381/using-java-runtime-to-add-registry-key-cause-process-reg-exe-to-run-forever)

But I'm using C++ and WinExec() and I don't know how to use the solution that has been given there for Java in my code.

My code is:

```
int result = 
WinExec("CMD.EXE /C REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\... /v Data1 /t Reg_SZ 
    /d \"cmd.exe /C ...\"", SW_HIDE);
```

I have tried to change it to:

```
int result = 
WinExec("CMD.EXE /C REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\... /v Data1 /t Reg_SZ 
    /d \"cmd.exe /C ...\" > 0", SW_HIDE);
```

But it gives me the same result.

So how to "consume" the process' output and close all streams in proper way? I guess CMD.EXE stays alive as well after executing (0% CPU, egists forever).

Comment: REG ADD is asking you for permission to overwrite the existing value. You never answer that question so it waits forever. Since you are already writing C++ why not just call RegSetValueEx yourself?

Comment: Tried running the whole command string manually? Could be that reg is sitting at a prompt waiting for input or something.

Comment: Indeed, the reg was sitting a prompt. Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on comments under my post, I checked if `reg.exe` is sitting a prompt and that was the point!

I added `/f` option for `REG` to confirm silently:

```
int result = 
WinExec("CMD.EXE /C REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\... /v Data1 /t Reg_SZ /f
    /d \"cmd.exe /C ...\"", SW_HIDE);
```

Thank you **Marc B** and **Raymond Chen** :)

I am using existing code with about 1k lines that contains WinExec("...") so I did not really wanted to rewrite them all to RegSetValueEx and others (not only `REG` is called that way).